# How do I test what port 8443 does on Tomcat 7.0, on Windows 7?

Tags: tomcat, server.xml

I would be making changes to Tomcat's 7 sever.xml file specifically port 8443 to 443, but I

don't know how to test port 8443 in the first place, with 8080, I could test with

localhost:8080, but how can I test with 8443, I have already tried with localhost:8443, but

it says that "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8443". I have

made some research into this but it seems that every time there is a reference to port 8443,

it talks about installing a certificate which is most likely what I have to do next.

Comment: you can try netstat -o command to check port association with processess ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "test port 8443"? This port in Tomcat is by default used for SSL connection.

Better see tomcat documentation for SSL: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: With port 8080 when you use localhost:8080, a tomcat successful installation page appears, with 8443, I only get this error Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8443 is that what is expected from port 8443 even though its the default ?

Comment: Yes, it's expected, since you haven't setup Tomcat for using SSL authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Since 8443 is ssl, you will need to use https to connect to the site. Try https://localhost:8443. If you have not setup the certificates correclty, you might get some ssl related errors. Is there a reason behind asking this question ?

Comment: Yes its part of a coursework. I am now in the process of setting up the certificate, but that's proving to be tricky as well.